# iPhone and any other Smartphone peer-to-peer communication over bluetooth

Tags: iphone, android, bluetooth, symbian, p2p

I want to build a simple bluetooth chat program that can do a 2 way chat with 2 mobile devices.

I know that I can use gamekit to develop such application for iphone and ipod touch. But I want to know is, is it possible for other smart phones (running my application) to discover and communicate with iphones and other devices as well?

in simple: I want my application to run on iphone, symbian and android and to be able to discover and communicate with each other over bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
http://android.noisepages.com/2010/02/yes-android-can-do-zeroconfbonjour-jmdns/

[zeroconf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) seems to be the generic technology behind Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for discovery or communication with arbitrary Bluetooth devices in the iOS SDK.